# Need help for Adobe XD design to Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, web, adobe

I have a simple adobe xd design and I converted to flutter widgets. But all widgets is not sorted like respective folder and is making me more confuse. All need to add provider, getx, localisation (it will be more than 1 language) and use responsive framework. Also I have a concern for web app security as well as how to add some SEO to may index page.

I try to get some paid help from various flutter group on Facebook and fiver but nobody tell me they can manage to organize the widgets for me. All of them talk about Flutter Web is not stable.

All I need a good documentation or video tutorial so I can start dig in make something beautiful with flutter web.

I am open to any suggestion. Thanks